# Блок внутри контейнера на всю ширину

Tags: css, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы блок был на всю ширину экрана, при этом данный блок находится внутри родительского контейнера у которого есть свои отступы, т.е. родительский блок не на всю ширину экрана.
Пытался сделать так, но что-то не получается сделать правильное вычисление при 'resize`.

https://jsfiddle.net/pke8L4sn/

```js
var w = $(window).width();
var $fullWidth = $('.custom_full_width');
function set_full_width($fullWidth){
  $fullWidth.each(function(i,el){
    var $row = $(el);
    var offsetLeft = $row.offset().left;
    $row.css({
      transform: 'translateX('+ -offsetLeft+'px)',
      width: w
    })
  });
}
set_full_width($fullWidth);
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  $fullWidth.length && set_full_width($fullWidth);
});
```

```css
.parent{
  padding: 30px;
  width: 80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.container{
  width: 100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  height: 400px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="container custom_full_width">content</div>
</div>
```

**P.S.**
Как сделать чтобы вложенный блок был на всю ширину экрана? 
https://jsfiddle.net/qmvtk40u/

Comment: @Sevastopol', что не понятного, мой вариант не рабочий. Суть вот: "Как сделать чтобы вложенный блок был на всю ширину экрана?"

Comment: @Sevastopol', поправил вопрос, случайно неправильно создал стили

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если правильно понял

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  padding: 30px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.custom_full_width {
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container custom_full_width">content</div>
</div>
```